# How to get one MovieClip from several external SWFs. AS2

Tags: printing, flash, actionscript-2, movieclip, bitmapdata

That is my question. I have many swf files with AS2 inside and I know that all of them has MovieClip named "viewport". So, I need to print all frames from these MovieClips.

I tried to do this with printjob class, but function my_pj.addPage(...) always returns false, and I have no idea why.

So I decided to use simple print(mc,"bframes") function. That's why I need to have only one MovieClip with all frames of all viewport MovieClips.

Please tell how to get one MovieClip from many swf's MovieClips, that was loaded by MovieClipLoader.loadClip.

If it possible with using BitmapData class, note how to copy ALL frames of MC to new one, please.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- [MovieClipLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00000410.html) to get many swfs into one parent swf
- [nextFrame](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00000582.html) to paginate between frames
- [printAsBitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00000595.html) to print each frame
- [swapDepths](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00001358.html) to switch movie clips